# XSLT Identity Transformation while removing all attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

Alright folks, yet another XSLT question. This transformation consists of 2 actions that I have working individually in 2 different XSLTs but that I can't for the life of me combine.

I'm trying to create an identity transformation that selects a node set, and also removes all attributes. Here's what I'm working with:

Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <meta>
        <data>
            <uselessMeta>SomeValue</uselessMeta>
        </data>
    </meta>
    <dataWrapper>
        <data xmlns:xfa="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <neededData1 meanAttribute="NotWanted">TransformMe!</neededData1>
            <neededData2 meanAttribute="NotWanted">TransformMe!</neededData2>
        </data>
    </dataWrapper>
</doc>
```

XSLT 1 (Identity Transform):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//dataWrapper/data[text() != '']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

XSLT 2: [XSLT - remove all attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795152/xslt-remove-all-attributes)

Wanted Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns:xfa="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <neededData1>TransformMe!</neededData1>
    <neededData2>TransformMe!</neededData2>
</data>
```

The problem seems to be that I am trying to match either the root (`/`) or all nodes (`node()`) but that I can't use `<xsl:copy-of />` and `<xsl:apply-templates />` together. Things to note:

- Xalan (JDK 1.7)
- XSLT 1.0

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `xsl:copy-of` in your first XSLT, you `xsl:apply-templates` which can then select the templates in your second XSLT (once combined with the first). `xsl:copy-of` just copies the existing node without making any changes or applying any other templates.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <a>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//dataWrapper/data[text() != '']" />
            </a>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that I have remove the match on `@*` from the identity template, so it just matches `node()`. Having two templates that match the same thing with the same priority may be raised as an error by some processors, although they may also pick the last matching template. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict)

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I was so focused on a single template match that matching more than once never crossed my mind. This also worked flawlessly in Xalan. Thank you!