# Is there a way to remove XML Tag Name attributes in NiFi

Tags: xml, apache-nifi

is there some way that nifi could remove the attributes inside the XML tag name? Please advise

Example:

```
<Kitchen><Plate unit="gram" index="1">Round Plate</Plate><Bottle unit="litres" weight="gram">Nalgene</Bottle></Kitchen>
```

to something like:

```
<Kitchen><Plate>Round Plate</Plate><Bottle>Nalgene</Bottle></Kitchen>
```

Appreciate for anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: Use `TransformXml` processor, refer this - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/

Comment: Hi @VikramsinhShinde, Is there any example that you could advise ? thanks

Comment: `TransformXml` configuration is intuitive, you just need to understand XSLT transformation. Please refer to this as a starting point - 
https://gist.github.com/cpburnz/6cc05c4a0ea4d66e875ccbebbd6eda4a AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795152/xslt-remove-all-attributes